# Dropbox icon missing in Elementary OS Odin

Tags: wingpanel, release-odin, odin, dropbox

The dropbox icon is missing from the wing panel (system tray) in Elementary OS Odin. I got it working barely in Hera using solutions on this website but with glitchy UI. Has anyone successfully found a solution to this problem? This is the only thing standing between me and elementary OS Odin. Thank you.

Comment: Solution is here [Wingpanel Ayatana-Compatibility Indicator](https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana).

Comment: The solution recommended by Boris here worked flawlessly. Just follow the instructions carefully and you will have a working wingpanel with 3rd party app icons. Thanks, Boris.